# Comparing elements of a Fortran matrix to the average of the entire matrix and remembering the index of the number closest to it

Tags: fortran

As the title says, I am having trouble seeing which one of the elements is closest to the average of the entire matrix.

I thought that subtracting an element in the matrix with the average and then doing the same to the next element and then comparing them I would get some results, but I don't think I've done that correctly.

```
subroutine PP(mat,N,x,y)
dimension mat(100,100)
r = 0
counter = 0
do i = 1,N
do j = 1,N

r = r + mat(i,j)
counter = counter + 1

enddo
enddo

average = r / counter

x=1
y=1

do i = 1,N
do j = 1,N

if(mat(i,j).ge.0)then
position1 = average - mat(i,j)
elseif(mat(i,j).lt.0)then
position1 = average + mat(i,j)
endif

if(mat(i+1,j).ge.0)then
position2 = average - mat(i+1,j)
elseif(mat(i+1,j).lt.0)then
position2 = average + mat(i+1,j)
endif

if(position1.lt.position2)then

endif

enddo
enddo
return
end

Program Example
dimension mat(100,100)

read*,N

read*,((mat(i,j),j=1,N),i=1,N)

call PP(mat,N,x,y)

print*,x
print*,y

end
```

Comment: Apologies,I've tried writing,but I named the variables in my native language,I'm gonna try and change the names around and post it then.
Thank you!

Comment: As you are new to Fortran, Fortran is a column major language.  When writing nested do-loops, you want the left-most index to varying the fastest.  Code that computes the average has the loops reversed.

Comment: Meaning i should change
do i = 1,N
do j = 1,N

r = r + mat(i,j)

to

do i = 1,N
do j = 1,N

r = r + mat(j,i)

?

Comment: Yes.  Column-major means that `mat(1,1), mat(2,1), mat(3,1) ...` are in consecutive memory locations.  If you use access the array by `mat(1,1), mat(1,2), mat(1,3) ...`, then `mat(1,1)` and `mat(1,2)` are `N * size of an element`  apart in memory.  If `N` is large you can blow out the memory cache, which can drastically slow down a program.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind.
Thank you very much!

Comment: You say this is for an assignment. I'll just say I fail my students if they do not use Implicit None - get into the habit, if you get into coding it will save you hours of your life.

Comment: Are you sure you are using `IMPLICIT NONE`?  It is really necessary. You still have one `pozicija2` in your code.

Comment: Using IMPLICIT NONE doesn't make sense,as they are teaching us to use i,j,k,l,m,n,o to decide if something is an integer.

I agree,it's dumb,but we are using fortran just as an introduction into programming as it is not difficult(at least that's what they have told me).

Comment: Make a habit of it you won't regret it! When a programming language is taught it is, in my opinion, very bad to teach bad habits (in this case not using `IMPLICIT NONE`) even / especially for an introduction into programming.

Comment: Using implicit typing in this century is very bad. Teaching using it should be a criminal offence, it cripples the mind.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have Fortran on this machine so there may be some syntactic errors in what follows.  First, let's find the mean of all the values in `mat`:

```
mean = sum(mat)/size(mat)
```

Next, we want to find the position of the element closest to that mean.  The expression

```
abs(mat-mean)
```

returns the absolute value of differences between elements in the array and the mean, and the function call

```
minloc(abs(mat-mean))
```

returns an integer array giving the location within the array at which the minimum difference is found.  In this case `minloc` will return a 2-element integer array giving the location of that minimum.  If there are multiple positions with the same value `minloc` returns only the first one found.

A potential problem with my approach is that the subexpression `abs(mat-mean)` will very probably require the creation of a temporary matrix; this might be time-consuming and it is certainly memory-consuming.  If either is a critical issue consider a loop-based approach instead.

As an aside: the way you have written your code does not ensure that when it executes the value of `N` known to the subroutine is `100` so there is a possibility of not examining every element of the array, and a possibility of wandering outside the array's bounds.  The approach I've outlined above avoids such problems, since it is never explicit about how many elements to examine.

Comment: Thanks for this,but i suppose I'll have to figure something out on my own.This is for a faculty assignment and i doubt they'd let me use code we haven't learned there yet.